# RPi can't connect to internet via Mac internet sharing

Tags: ssh, ethernet, internet

I have a mac and raspberry pi connected via ethernet cable which are communicated fine. Internet sharing is turned on but my raspberry pi can't connect to the internet.

My mac is connected to the internet via Wifi with the following settings:
 [image]

Internet is working on my mac and have connected an ethernet cable between my mac and my raspberry pi. I turned on internet sharing on my mac and gave the ethernet the following settings:
[image]

I gave my raspberry pi a static IP address in the same subnet (192.168.1.20) by editing the  network/interaces file and set the gateway the same as my Macs ip address, which looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.90
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

I can ping from my RPi to my mac (ping 192.168.1.90) and can ssh into my RPi from my mac (set up previously; ssh pi@192.168.1.20).

**The problem**: I can't seem to connect to the internet. Running `sudo apt-get update` shows errors in the lines of "temporary failure resolving archive.raspberrypi.org'. Any help or advice is appreciated.

**Update 1:** The output of "route" is (after waiting many seconds):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: try changing the gateway to the router ip address of 192.168.1.254

Comment: I tried but 'sudo apt-get update' still gives the same error that it cannot connect..

Comment: what is the output of the command "route"? and can you ping google.com?

Comment: I added the output of "route" to the post above. If I type "ping google.com" nothing happens and after a long while it says "ping: unknown host google.com"

Comment: Do you have the DNS set correctly? I also had an issue with Mac Internet Sharing, and rebooting fixed my issue.

Comment: How would I know the DNS is set correctly? I tried rebooting but it didn't help.

Comment: Don't set static IPs for both of the ethernet adaptors.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer please? My mac got the ip address 192.168.1.90 from the router, then I set that as static for the ethernet that connects to the RPi so that it can find the mac.

Comment: The problem is still unresolved..

Answer (score 2):

Your route is incorrect:
default         192.168.1.254

If your gateway (in this case the Mac) is at .1.90, your gateway has to be at .1.90

If you have just set the fixed IP in network/interfaces, then you may need to restart your networking stack (/etc/init.d/network restart).

Also check your current network configuration with "ifconfig eth0", you may see the problem right there. To fix your route do this: "route add default gw 192.168.1.90"

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable this in 'Sharing' under 'Settings'

Follow this

http://millibit.blogspot.com/2014/12/ceph-pi-making-pi-with-mac.html#internet_sharing

Comment: the link is not working anymore.