# I can't SSH or connect my Pi via Ethernet

Tags: ssh, ethernet, internet

So I'm running an Ethernet cable from my Mac to my Pi, network sharing is enabled on my Mac. Here's what my setup looks like

[image]

So I head over to my Pi and try `ping google.com`, I get

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Here's what I get when I try to SSH into the server

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.2.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

My `ifconfig` on the Pi
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output from ifconfig.

Comment: All set, sorry for the picture, copying it over would of been a long process @SteveRobillard

Comment: try SSHing to 10.0.0.5. so in your case SSH pi@10.0.0.5

Comment: Still getting the `Connection refused` error @SteveRobillard

Comment: The source of the problem seems to be that the Pi and Mac are not on the same network one is on 10.0.0.5 and the other is on 192.168.2.2. Second the Pi has an IP adress but does not appear to have any DNS servers or gateway - hence you get a failure when pinging Google.

Comment: Have you seen this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/rpi-cant-connect-to-internet-via-mac-internet-sharing?rq=1

Comment: Shouldn't RPi be in the same subnet as your computer ? Try assigning a static IP of the same subnet (192.168.2.xx) to your rpi by modifying `/etc/network/interfaces` as per this guide http://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address and reboot. And try SSHing IP you assigned after reboot. Hope it helps.